# Django Translations only partially working

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

I've done `makemessages` and `compilemessages` and both files contain the translation that is inside a {% blocktranslate %}. I've even re-run makemessages to make sure nothing changed in the msgid and it did not make any change to my .po file except for the `POT-Creation-Date`. But these {% blocktranslate %} paragraphs are not translating.  I'm stuck with the `msgid` instead of the `msgstr`.

Is there some trick to very long msgid's?

I'm assuming the keys don't match, but not sure why they don't match since the tools don't change the values when re-run.

---

The problem has gotten worse, now some of the short translations just aren't working either.

Here is the rendered page:

[image: 1/4 Translated UI]

Here is the source that renders it:

```
            <li class="nav-item {% is_active_tab 'home' %}">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home' %}">
                    {% translate "Home" %}
                </a>
            </li>
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item {% is_active_tab 'games:list' %}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'games:list' %}">
                        {% translate "My Quizzes" %}
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item {% is_active_tab 'games:create' %}">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'games:create' %}">
                        {% translate "New Quiz" %}
                    </a>
                </li>
```

And here is the .po file

```
#: templates/site_base.html:41
msgid "Home"
msgstr "Inicio"

#: templates/site_base.html:47
msgid "My Quizzes"
msgstr "Mis Cuestionarios"

#: templates/site_base.html:52
#, fuzzy
msgid "New Quiz"
msgstr "Nuevo Cuestionario"
```

Yes, I have run compilemessages

```
(bb) $ manage compilemessages
     processing file django.po in .../locale/es_MX/LC_MESSAGES
```

And based on the first translation it is finding the file, but then it only translates a few of the terms.  The Admin translations are better (more complete) but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I thought it might be `LOCALE_PATHS` so I added this to my settings but then remembered that compilemessages was already finding the file so that had no effect....

```
LOCALE_PATHS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'locale',
]
```

---

Update:
I was using the locale of es_MX.  When I converted back to just es, it started working, and removing the #fuzzy was the other part of the fix.  I'm not sure how you do variations on spanish, but for the moment, I'm just not worrying about that.

Comment: Have you got `{% load i18n %}` template tag in your template file?

Comment: Are you looking at the right part of the template code? Where is the else part to request.user.is_authenticated? And what's your LANGUAGES settings and the [active language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#get-current-language)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not show any `{% blocktranslate %}` so it is hard to provide an appropriate answer.

For the short translation, the `#, fuzzy` disallow the .po entry to be used and it won't translate.

Comment: It's possible he used `--use-fuzzy`, but either way it doesn't explain "My Quizzes".

Comment: I don't see enough of your project to provide better adivices. A greater part of your template and the generated html would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate variations of Spanish such as es_MX, then:

- ./manage.py makemessages -l es_MX
- set `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-MX'` in your settings.py

NB: notice the difference, underscore for makemessages, and minus for settings!